# Hyphen/dash 'and'-separated words in the same phrase: is this usage correct?

Tags: grammar, writing-style

I have a phrase like this:

> John enjoys translating economics- and IT- related articles

Is this a correct usage of the words `economics-` and `IT-` `related`? I think I saw such method of joining separate words that refer to the same common idea - `related` in this case, but can't help but wonder if it sounds clumsy to a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called suspensive hyphenation, and you used it correctly, except you need to close the space between IT- and related.

> John enjoys translating economics- and IT-related articles

Here's the AP stylebook entry on suspensive hyphenation:

> SUSPENSIVE HYPHENATION: The form: He received a 10- to 20-year
>   sentence in prison.